# Logout Button in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, logout

How can I create logout button if my login controller with session is like this?

```
function login_user() {   
    $user_login = array(  
         'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),  
         'password'=>$this->input->post('password')
    );
    $data=$this->Infoserbilis_model->login_user($user_login['username'],$user_login['password']);
    if($data) {
       $session_data['logged_in'] = TRUE;
       $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
       //$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);
       redirect('Infoserbilis/admin_page', 'refresh');   
    } else {
       echo '<script>alert("Invalid Username or Password");</script>';
       redirect('Infoserbilis/index', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

I have tried `$this->session->sess_destroy();` on my function logout but to no avail. Thanks in advance

```
public function logout() {

// Removing session data
$this->session->sess_destroy();
echo '<script>alert("Bye!");</script>';
redirect('Infoserbilis/index', 'refresh');
}
```

Comment: what is the error message when trying `sess_destroy`

Comment: no error. its just staying on my admin page. not logging out. thanks for your response.

Comment: `sess_destroy` just destory current session, can't redirect page for you, you need redirect page manually, see my answer. @jb naron

Comment: my logout code has redirect. but still to no avail. sorry i didn't include my logout controller.

Comment: `logout()` redirects to 'Infoserbilis/index' which IS the admin page... right? Where do you really want it to go? Put that controller/method in the `redirect()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, base on your message, `$this->session->sess_destroy()` just only destroy the current session, you need redirect page manually. Write the specific route you want to redirect to in `redirect()` function

```
/**
 * logout
 */
public function logout()
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();

    redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function logout() {

            $this->session->unset_userdata('is_searched');
            redirect('CONTROLLER/login');
                   }
```

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the problem, some explanation would go a long way to understanding how you've solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting to `index` function in `Infoserbilis` controller. Check session is active or not in that function.
Here is an example :

```
public function index() {
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == true){
        //load the required view
    }
    else {
        redirect('controller/login');
    }
}
```

or you can redirect to `login` from `logout` function

```
public function logout() {
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('controller/login');
}
```